# Javascript If else statement not working with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rest

I have the following code. So basically the JavaScript needs to look at the username and password and check it via an API (which works) and returns true or false. True giving the user access to the next page and false reloading the login page. 
 **Everything works perfectly except for the JavaScript if statement.**  
My code is as follows:

```js
var ApiKey = '';  //generated API Key
var userPass = document.getElementById('pass');  //gets the password
var userName = document.getElementById('usr');   //gets the username

function testAJAX(){
$.getJSON("http://mywebsitesapiaddress.com/api" + ApiKey +"&user="+ userName.value + "&pass=" + userPass.value, function(data) {
    if (data.success == "true") {
        window.location = "mainpage.html";
    }
    else {
      location.reload();
    }
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="username" id="usr" placeholder="Enter your username">
<input type="password" name="password" id="pass" placeholder="Enter your password">
<button onclick="testAJAX()" id ="login">Login</button>
```

Comment: try `if (data.success == true) {` or just `if (data.success) {`

Comment: What are you getting in response? And did you try `if (data.success){}else{}` or  `if (data.success==true){}else{}`

Comment: Unrelated, but what stops someone from inspecting your source and manually going to `mainpage.html` - do you have server side checking on that page too?

Comment: Show us the returned JSON, in particular, the JSON that holds `"success":"true"`.

Comment: if(data.success == true ){   <-- remove quotes

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes you are correct, but this is used in an application where the source cannot be inspected, and if someone manages to navigate to that page directly it would not show any information because all information is based on the unique login and password of the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When JSON data is true or false. Double quotes cannot be used.**
Thank you for the quick responses. Turns out the problem was that the datatypes are clashing, I changed the API response to 1 and 0 and that seemed to have solved the problem. Easier and more flexible when using numbers.

```
var ApiKey = '';  //generated API Key
var userPass = document.getElementById('pass');  //gets the password
var userName = document.getElementById('usr');   //gets the username

function testAJAX(){
$.getJSON("http://mywebsitesapiaddress.com/api" + ApiKey +"&user="+ userName.value + "&pass=" + userPass.value, function(data) {
    if (data.success == 1) {
        window.location = "mainpage.html";
    }
    else {
      location.reload();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question that you asked.

Comment: adapted the answer @spender

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, except for the type of the `success` property value.

It could be that the server is not returning a string literal `'true'` instead a boolean value `true` so

```
if (data.success) { //or data.success === true
  window.location = "mainpage.html";
} else {
  location.reload();
}
```

Comment: With JS coercion, isn't `"false"` truthy? This might be a dangerous fix.

Comment: @spender that depends on the api, if we know what will be type of returned value then it is safe to go with it IMHO